# customize bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, shell, bash-completion

How to customize bash autocomplete to list the files in another directory for only one script option (-seq), for other script options (-speed, -define) default autocomplete is O.K. this is what I have

```
 export files=`ls /home/tests/`
 echo $files #debug     

 _xtest ()   {                .
      local cur
      COMPREPLY=()     cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
       #case "$cur" in
       COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) )
    #  esac
      return 0
    }

    complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```

When I try to run from shell I get the below message before the list of files

```
> xtest -seq [TAB][TAB]

 bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

Is there a way not to receive this message before the file list ?
How to enable default bash completion for other options ?

Comment: There's a `.` char in the `_xtest() {` line.

Comment: wow ! yes that was the reason for the message @pynexj

Answer (score 0):

should use $prev instead of $cur :

```
_xtest ()   {              
      local prev
      COMPREPLY=()     
      prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}
      case "$prev" in
       -seq )
          COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) ) ;;
      esac
      return 0
    }
complete -F _xtest -o filenames xtest
```